# ImportError: No module named 'pymysql.cursors'

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

I am beginner in python and want to use database.I have followed following link for database access.
[steps](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/)

The output of steps which i has used as following :

**Command**

```
pip3 -V
```

**Result**

```
pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

**Second Command**

```
pip3 install PyMySQL
```

**Result**

```
Requirement already satisfied: PyMySQL in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/PyMySQL-0.9.2-py3.5.egg (0.9.2)
```

While i was using script to access database i got following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "pymysql.py", line 2, in <module>
import pymysql.cursors
File "/var/www/cgi-bin/pymysql.py", line 2, in <module>
import pymysql.cursors
ImportError: No module named 'pymysql.cursors'; 
`enter code here`'pymysql' is not a package
```

**Environment** :

OS - Ubuntu 16.04

Python version - Python 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command,

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```